# How to calculate value of expressions when $a = 22$

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$a = 22$

Round the answer to three significant figures:

$\dfrac{77}{3a}$ for this one I am not sure if I do $\dfrac{77}{3(22)} = 1.17$ or $\dfrac{77}{3(22)} = 56$.

Sorry if this is written in a confusing way.

Comment: 77 over 3a means $\frac{7}{3a}$ = $\frac{7}{66}$. So your first answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{77}{3a}$ means you will just replace $a$ in the formula with $22$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{77}{3*22}$ = $\dfrac{77}{66}$ = $1.1666$ or, when rounded to 3 significant figures, $1.17$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{77a}{3}=\frac{77}{3}\times a$ whereas you have $\frac{77}{3a}=\frac{77}{3}\div a$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{77}{3a}=\frac{77}{3\cdot22}=\frac{7\cdot11}{3\cdot 2\cdot 11}=\frac{7\cdot \not 11}{3\cdot 2\cdot \not 11}=\frac{7}{6}=1+\frac{1}{6}=1.167$$